# Css how can i find a css file from inspector

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have to search the exact css file where it has been a change on a rule but i can't remember where is this rule. How can find the css file from inspector ?

Comment: right click, choose inspect element and will open the styles tab on your right and u can see the classes that holds the css and as well on right top will show in which file name is that class.

Comment: If you are using FF press F12 to open developer tools -> Inspector tab -> On the right side Rules tab. The CSS file name would be shown besides the css style rule. Same goes for IE and Chrome, only the names differ

Answer (score 2):

There is a CSS file name near the selector (`primary-unified-...` for example)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open developer console and find the Sources tab. There you can find all loaded resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think cmd+f or ctrl+f in elements/networks panel will fuzzy search your css files.